# The equivalent of path_lookup() of linux 2.6 in linux 3.7

Tags: linux, kernel, vfs

I am reading "Understanding the Linux Kernel" 3rd edition, by D.Bovet & M.Cesati. In the chapter about Virtual file systems, they refer to the function "path_lookup()" that does the lookup for a given path. The book is based on linux-2.6.
I am viewing files in linux-3.7.6 and I can't find the function (using cscope tool). Any idea what's the equivalent function in this version of linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On current kernel versions you can achieve the same using vfs_path_lookup() (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/namei.c#L2051).

Comment: Well the function "path_lookup()" another parameters, but "vfs_path_lookup()" leads to the same "link_walk_path()" function. Thank you.